# How to Use DateTime of ODATA (SMP 9.0 and above) in Android

Tags: java, android, odata, smp

I am getting ODATA from SMP from that ODATA. When we are trying to fetch Datetime and setting into Java Date getting an Exception. How to Typecast ODATA DateTime to Java Date in Android (SMP 9.0 and above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After three hours of search I got the expected solution from SAP Community blog
Actually I was trying below one

```
if (property !=null) { 
     ObjName.setDate((Date)property.getValue());
   }
```

But I was getting exception due to in proper Typecast.
We need to Typecast ODATA **Edm.DateTime** with **GregorianCalendar** in Android like

```
 if (property !=null) { 
          ObjName.setDate( (GregorianCalendar) property.getValue());
        }
```

**Note**:In above code setDate() is setter method.

For Detail Description :
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/mobility-platform/blog/2015/08/15/handling-datetime-from-frontend-with-odata-in-native-android-app-using-smp-30][1]

Comment: You can also typecast it to Calendar (: